# One to one relationship insert order in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, flush, one-to-one

I have two Entities that have a one-to-one associtation between each other. 
Both Entities have composite natural primary keys. One entity uses 1 field from its natural composite key and one extra column to reference the other entity.
I have the problem with persisting these entities, Hibernate first inserts referencing objects (per my understanding it is HallPlacesSchema) so I get constraint violation error right away before the referenced objects are inserted (Hall).

```
CREATE TABLE webgatemarket_TssHallPlacesSchema (
  TSSHALLPLACESSCHEMAID            INTEGER          NOT NULL,
  WEBGATEMARKET_ID                 INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  TSSHALLID                        INTEGER          NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (TSSHALLPLACESSCHEMAID, WEBGATEMARKET_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (WEBGATEMARKET_ID, TSSHALLID) REFERENCES webgatemarket_TssHall(WEBGATEMARKET_ID, TSSHALLID),
  FOREIGN KEY (WEBGATEMARKET_ID) REFERENCES webgatemarkets (cinema_id),
  INDEX (WEBGATEMARKET_ID, TSSHALLPLACESSCHEMAID)
) ENGINE =InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;

CREATE TABLE webgatemarket_TssHall (
  TSSHALLID           INTEGER          NOT NULL,
  WEBGATEMARKET_ID    INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (TSSHALLID, WEBGATEMARKET_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (WEBGATEMARKET_ID) REFERENCES webgatemarkets (cinema_id)
) ENGINE =InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;


public class DataObjectPk implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WEBGATEMARKET_ID")
    private WebGateMarketDO webGateMarket;
}

@IdClass(DataObjectPk.class)
public class Hall
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TSSHALLID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WEBGATEMARKET_ID")
    private WebGateMarketDO webGateMarket;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "hall")
    private HallPlacesSchema hallPlacesSchema;
}

@IdClass(DataObjectPk.class)
public class HallPlacesSchema extends DataObject
{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WEBGATEMARKET_ID")
    private WebGateMarketDO webGateMarket;

    @Column(name = "TSSHALLID")
    private Integer hallId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "TSSHALLID", referencedColumnName = "TSSHALLID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "WEBGATEMARKET_ID", referencedColumnName = "WEBGATEMARKET_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Hall hall;
}
```

The problem appears when in a single session I persist Hall(s) and then HallPlacesSchema(s), exactly in that order.

```
entityManager.persist(halls); 
entityManager.persist(hallPlacesSchemas);
entityManager.flush();
```

When the session flushes I see that Hibernate first INSERTs HallPlacesSchema objects, so I immediately get constraint violation error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails....

Can anybody help me to understand why is that ?

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert HallPlacesSchema
        */ insert 
        into
            webgatemarket_TssHallPlacesSchema
            (DELFLAG, UPDATENUM, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_BACKGROUND, TSSHALLID, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_HEIGHT, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_ISDEFAULT, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_NAME, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_PLACE_HEIGHT, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_PLACE_WIDTH, SAREAID, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_SCALE_FACTOR, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_SECTORS_COUNT, TSSHALLPLACESCHEMA_WIDTH, TSSHALLPLACESSCHEMAID, WEBGATEMARKET_ID) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2014-06-28 22:31:39,126 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] : SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
2014-06-28 22:31:39,126 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard my question, there was a bug in my test classes that caused the insertion of HallPlacesSchema first, explicitly.